# How could the Resolute receive Robinson's Jupiter response?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-in-space-2018

In the last episode of *Lost in Space* Season 1, how could the *Resolute* receive Jupiter's response if the *Resolute*'s antenna fell to the planet after the incident with the robot?

If the *Resolute* could receive that transmission, why didn't they receive the survivor's transmissions from the planet when orbiting over the survivor's camp?

Here is the transcipt of the actual conversation. I don't remember all the names, but you see Maureen, John and Victor talking to eachother:

> - It's the Resolute! Robinsons, Jupiter 2, you are clear to dock.
> - You waited for us.
> - Victor: John, I represent every member of this colonist group, even you. - John: Victor thank you. You're welcome. Sir, we're near the orbit
> - Quickly, please. We've stayed longer than we should.
> - Maureen: Actually, we're out of fuel. Hold tight.
> - Victor: We'll come to you.
> - It's the noise the robot's ship was making.
> - So why is our ship making it? What's going on? Why Why are we turning around?
> - Victor: Jupiter 2, is everything okay?
> - Maureen: I don't know. It's like we lost control of the ship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could the Resolute receive Jupiter's response.

## Dhar can use the radios from the *already* docked Jupiter craft.

Initially, all communications are from the *Resolute* in the *hopes* that the Jupiter crew can hear them.

> Jupiter 2 this is Victor Dhar calling you from the Resolute.
>
> **I don't know if you can hear us**, but every one of the other Jupiters made it here safely.
>
> And for that, we owe you a debt of gratitude.
>
> However, as you're well aware, there's a black hole making this section of space extremely treacherous.
>
> You now have 63 minutes to join us. I hope you will. Because after that time, we simply can't wait any longer.
>
> Resolute, out.

The *Resolute* can't hear them for the very reason you have stated...no antenna.

Once the other Jupiter craft had docked with the *Resolute*, Dhar can use **their** radios to contact the Robisons' Jupiter craft.

Comment: But at the end of the episode, they have a conversation, Victor told the jupiter to go to Resolute, then Maureen told him they havent more fuel, then Victor said "no problem we go to catch you", but jupiter starting to drift and Maureen told Victor they couldnt control the jupiter when Victor asked her why the jupiter was modifying it's direction and then the jupiter disappear in that wormhole.

It was an actual conversation, they were communicating.

Comment: Ok, the radios make sense, they are communicating through their radios not through Resolute antenna.

Answer (score 2):

There is long range (multidirectional) transmission, and there is small range (mono directional) transmission.

Your smartphone doesn't have an antenna (or it look like it), but if you check a SatPhone, you will notice that there is a big antenna (maybe not the most recent, but all the one we saw in movies, and 98% of the results of google image for Satellite phone).
Try to use your SatPhone without the Antenna, it will fail. Yet once you will be in range of a radio Tower, you will be able to use your smartphone (and probably your SatPhone in local mode).

That's the same difference than shouting to someone that is 100 meters in front of you while waiving your arms versus shouting to someone that is 'somewhere in your city'.